# GCC warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

Using the following command

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi -std=c99 -fstack-protector-all -fstack-check -O3 root.c -o  rootTESTOBJECT
```

I get the compiler warning 
    root.h:76:22: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros

```
72 #ifdef Debug
73 #include <stdio.h>
74 #define crumb(phrase0...) printf(phrase0)
75 #else
76 #define crumb(phrase0...) 
77 #endif
```

I believe the option
    -ansi -std=c99 
allows the use of variadic macros, it does according to the docs anyway...

I have tried editing line 76 to

```
76 #define crumb(phrase0...) printf("")
```

to see if this fixed the warning but with no joy.

the compiler verion is Apple's gcc, version 4.2.1
I'm not sure if I need be too concerned by this but I really don't like warnings. What flag's am I missing ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`#define crumb(phrase0...) <whatever>` is giving a name (`phrase0`) to the variable arguments (`...`).

This is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html).

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) does define a way of passing variable arguments to macros (see §6.10.3/12 and §6.10.3.1/2): the variable arguments are unnamed
on the left-hand side of the definitions (i.e. just `...`), and referenced on the right-hand side as `__VA_ARGS__`, like this:

```
#define crumb(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

(By the way, your `gcc` arguments should not include both `-ansi` and `-std=c99`:  `-ansi` specifies the earlier C standard (known variously as ANSI C, C89 or C90); the combination of both options only happens to select C99 in this case because `-std=c99` appears *after* `-ansi` in the argument list, and the last one wins.)