# Cleaning up C/C++ code reveals problems with variadic macros

Tags: c++, c, macros, c99, variadic-macros

We're doing some code cleanup, fixing signed/unsigned comparisons, running static analysis, etc, on the code base of C, C++, and Java.

One of the warnings we're getting is

```
warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
```

And its companion warning

```
warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used
```

Now, in the C code I used the [C99 standard variadic macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6750512/2815) to fix the problem, but in the C++ code, what is the correct answer? Using the same C99 style results in a different warning

```
warning: anonymous variadic macros were introduced in C99
```

For which I don't see any answers.

We're using GCC (G++) 4.4.3 in Linux.

I'm hoping there is some flag, or other method that can correct, or disable it for the specific section of code - but its for the logging which is used in almost every file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Variadic macros nonstandard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786649/are-variadic-macros-nonstandard)

Comment: Use C++11. Type `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` on your GCC command line. Or just ignore the warning.

Comment: Yeah, using c++11 isn't yet in the cards, its just not supported well enough (yet)

Comment: So you're basically saying @Bo-Persson that there is no way to eliminate the warnings (short of turning them off) because variadic macros are not standard in C++ until c++11?

Comment: @Petri - I don't now of any other way. gcc 4.4.3 probably isn't aware of the latest changes to C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the gcc option `-Wno-variadic-macros` to disable that particular warning.

**Edit: (from comments)**

To disable the warning for a section of code but leave it on in general, use `#pragma GCC diagnostic` [described here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas).

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wvariadic-macros"

    // Your code and/or include files
    // (No variadic warnings here)

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable the warning for a section of code but leave it on in general? If I use this how do I disable `warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used`

Comment: @Petriborg: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

Comment: The pragma didn't work for me in stinky old gcc-4.2.3 but -Wno-variadic-macros did the job, so up-voted.

Comment: _That_ pragma didn't work for me either, but I got it working by `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wvariadic-macros"` (without the `no-`)

Comment: It seems GCC doesn't work with the pragma but Clang does